# AngularJS Directive: Pass dynamically created object as attribute for nested directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that wraps around another directive . The child directive accepts an "options" object as an attribute. I want to create this options object in the parent directive's link function and then set it as an attribute on the child directive in the parent's template, but the options object does not get set if its created dynamically. This works if the options object is set statically in the template itself.

I have a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/gNeKMcneO8RDBmlmpt72?p=preview
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!!

```
angular.module('nestedDirectives', [])
.directive('fruitinfo',
    [
        function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    fruitname: '@?'
                },
                template: '<br>Fruit Name: {{fruitname}}<br>Fruit Options: {{fruitoptions}}',

                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                  scope.fruitoptions = scope.$eval(attrs['fruitinfo']);
                }
            };
        }])
.directive('fruits',
    [
        function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    selectedFruits: '=?', 
                    btnSizeClass: "@?"
                },
                template: 'btnSizeClass: {{btnSizeClass}}<br>Fruits: {{fruits}}<br><div ' +
                    '         fruitinfo="fruitOptions" ' +
                    '         fruitname="{{f}}"' +
                    '         ng-repeat="f in fruits">' +
                    '</div><br><br>' +
                    '<div fruitname="With static fruitOptions: {{f}}" fruitinfo="{test: \'testOption\', btnSizeClass: \'btn-xs\'}" ng-repeat="f in fruits"></div>',

                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.fruitOptions = {test: 'testOption', btnSizeClass: scope.btnSizeClass};
                    scope.fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Watermelon', 'Strawberry'];


                }
            };
        }]
        )
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

any particular reason why you are using $eval instead of using "&" in your scope definition like this

http://plnkr.co/edit/W47LZsQ3i4zS8Feu7sDl?p=preview

if you use

```
fruitoptions:'&fruitinfo'
```

and then you do

```
scope.fruitoptions=$scope.fruitoptions()
```

in your link function you'll get the evaluated expression in its original scope, also consider doing this on the controller function which is invoked prior the link cycle

Comment: check out my plunker. You can put it in the child directive link or controller function

Comment: There are some instances where the markup creates a static object and some others where I need to dynamically provide the object. Thanks for the above tip and the plunkr. I need to modify my inner directive check whether  an object or a string has been provided for fruitinfo and then either use eval or the &

Comment: & uses evaul itself so you should be fine by just using it whether is a scope variable or a literal json defined it will evaluated too http://plnkr.co/edit/nvgl1pKenAqGevXl2RW8?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The "fruitOptions" value must be serialized so that the template can compile it as an attribute, which can then be converted back to an object using "eval" in the nested directive. Plunker updated.